# How to make % motion work with quotes?

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-motions

Is it possible to have % motion work with matching quote `"` or `'`?

For example if we have text:

```
"Lorem ipsum is placeholder text (commonly used in the graphic),
'print, and publishing industries' for previewing layouts and visual mockups"
```

I would love to jump to matching `'` or `"` when cursor is on one of them by pressing `%`. It works with all the brackets, i.e. `([{`, but nothing happens when standing on a bracket.

`:help 'matchpairs'` states that its not possible to match same character pairs. Is there a workaround for this limitation, because `vi"` works just fine?

Comment: We have several similar questions on this site, but I couldn't easily find an exact duplicate or one that offered a solution. The problem of course is that, without context, " has no direction, so in general what you're asking for isn't possible. It's easy to knock up _something_ with an expression mapping, but it gets a bit more complicated depending on precisely how you actually want it to work: it might be worth giving a few examples of how you'd want it to function on actual buffer contents (in particular, how you'd like it to handle edge cases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turned the best workaround I could come up with into a plugin: [vim-matchquote](https://github.com/airblade/vim-matchquote).

In a nutshell it figures out whether you are on an "odd" or "even" quotation mark character and [jumps forward or back](https://github.com/airblade/vim-matchquote/blob/4b409692f71e285355baa8f9dcf39bda211394ca/plugin/matchquote.vim#L66-L67) respectively.

The trickiness comes from [integrating with the various versions of matchit](https://github.com/airblade/vim-matchquote/blob/4b409692f71e285355baa8f9dcf39bda211394ca/plugin/matchquote.vim#L12-L39) that have been bundled with vim over the years.

Comment: Works like a charm :)

Comment: That's great to hear!